# Read NFC tag with iOS using Titanium Appcelerator

Tags: ios, nfc, appcelerator-titanium

I'm trying to develop an app to read an NFC tag with an iOS device using Titanium Appcelerator.

For that I'm using this example:

https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/ti.nfc/blob/master/ios/example/app.js

With the code in the example I'm able to detect an NFC device, the problem is that I can't read the message that inside the NFC device. I know that the NFC device has some message in it because when I use an android device I can read the content of it.

How can I get message that is in the NFC device?

Thanks

Comment: which kind of NFC tag do you want to read? You might need to have a look at this PR: https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/ti.nfc/pull/31

Comment: Hi, it is just text. On android I can read the text, but on iOS the message is alvays empty.

Comment: not the content but the type. There are different types of tags. And did you test the binary from the ticket that will add some more types and ios13 support (https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/MOD-2586)?

Comment: I have the latest version of iOS and ti.nfc, but  the tag I read is still always empty. I've looked everywhere but can't find a solution. I know my NFC works because I use another application from the store and I can read the contents of my NFC

Comment: so you are using ti.nfc 2.2.0, ti sdk 9.0.3.GA and iOS 13?

Comment: The last version of the ti.nfc module that I was able to get was the 2.1.0. Can you send me the link to download the 2.2.0 version so I can test it? I thought that the 2.1.0 was the last version. The ti sdk that I use is the 9.0.3.GA.

Comment: I got the version 2.2.0 from this link: https://github.com/hansemannn?tab=overview&org=appcelerator-modules&from=2020-02-01&to=2020-02-20 But after testing the result is the same. I get an empty message.